# SQLite: no such column error

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm getting the `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such colum: bla` error.

I have a sqlite file, which only consists of one table `foo` with column `bar`.

```
connection = lite.connect(db.sqlite)
def insertEvent(self, bar):            
    with connection:                                                          
        cur = connection.cursor()                                               
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES (bar);")

insertEvent("bla")
```

Is my syntax wrong or why am I getting the error? I couldn't find any useful solutions in all the other questions.

Just in case: I'm using the sqlite3 library.

Comment: You should be getting `no such column: bar`, unless you're code *really* says `VALUES (bla)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the insert statement to

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo(bar) VALUES (?);", (bar,))
```

You aren't using the `bar` parameter in the insert statement.

Comment: Works. I thought that `Values (bar)` would take the bar parameter. Can you explain what the comma after the `bar` does (`(bar,)`)?

Comment: The comma after `bar` makes it a tuple. All the `?` in the SQL statement are replaced by the values in the tuple. If you have multiple values to insert you just list them `(bar1, bar2, bar3)` but if you have a single value it needs the ,

Comment: I generally write [bar], which does not need the comma to differentiate between and expression an iterable.